# Simple java "Classes" and "Methods" questions

Tags: java, class, methods

Consider a Quadratic class, which maintains information about a quadratic expression `ax^2+bx+c`.

```
public class Quadratic
{
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    /*  Constructor: initializes all instance variables
     */
    public Quadratic(double aVal, double bVal, double cVal)
    {  //code omitted
    }

    /* This method determines and displays the real roots of 
     * the quadratic this.
     */

    public void displayRoots()
    { //code omitted.
    }

    /* Returns the value of this quadratic evaluated at xVal.
    */

    public double calcValue(double xVal)
    { //code omitted.
    }

} //end class
```

**So the question asked:**
Complete the constructor Quadratic, which initializes the instance variables to the value of the provided parameters.

```
public Quadratic (double aVal, double bVal, double cVal)
{     

}
```

Comment: What is _your_ question? Or are you just telling us what to do?

Comment: Did you mean : `// Please write code for me`, instead of `// code omitted` in all those places?

Comment: @RohitJain I think he just pasted his homework assignment on here.

Comment: How do you normally assign something?

Comment: It's not in the slightest bit unclear what the user's asking.  It could hardly be clearer.  Since there's only 1 question referred to, how could the question possibly be anything else?

Answer (score 1):

[In this example](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-constructor-tutorial)

```
class Language {
  String name;

  Language(String t) {
    name = t;
  }

  //rest of code

}
```

We have a class variable called `name`:

```
  String name;
```

However, name has no value at first, so we're assuming we're going to be passed this value via parameters:

```
Language(String t) {  //everything in the parenthesis are the parameters
```

The only parameter is `t`.  This will be passed in by some other method/class, but what do we do with it?  We should probably store it into our class variable as so:

```
    name = t;
```

This way you can save and use it for the methods you write.  ***You should be able to apply this same logic to what your assignment is asking for***.  Here are some other resources (there are plenty on the internet!):

http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/constructor.htm

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/constructors.html

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html

Comment: +1 for not writing his code for him.

Comment: name isn't a local variable.

Comment: @crush good point, let me update

Comment: class member would be better, but this is wasted effort on the person who asked this question anyways. its clear they don't want to put forth the effort to learn what they are in school to learn.